# How to add user to database and authorize user as well

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am learning angular with firebase. I am currently trying to create a user in firebase but also add that user to the database with their email and user Id.

I have a component that is calling my firebase service.

//register.component.ts

```
    import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  username:string;
  email:string;
  password:string;
  constructor(
   private firebaseService:FirebaseService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  OnSubmit()
  {
    this.firebaseService.register(this.username,this.email,this.password)
    .then( (res) =>{
      console.log("firebase has registered the user: "+ res);
    })
    .catch( (err)=>{
      console.log("There was an error registering: "+ err.message);
    });

  }
}
```

and this is the service
firebase.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "angularfire2/database"; 
import{ AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
 users: AngularFireList<any[]>;

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public  af: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.users = af.list('users/');
   }

  register(username:string, email:string, password:string)
  {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then( (userData) => {resolve(userData), 
      err => reject(err) });

    });
  }
}
```

I am not receiving any errors and the register function is creating the user as a registered user but I do not know how to add that user to the database in the path 'users/'

I know the userData object returned contains all of the user information but I do not know where in the .then part that I would write the code to add that user to the database. I know firebase has just recently changed to AngularFireList instead of AngularFireListObservables and that is making it hard to find answers.

Thank you for any help you are able to give. Been working on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question.

I went and studied promises in more detailed and learned that a promise can have chained .then functions. .then functions are called in order in which they are written and only fire when the previous promise has been completed.

so in the firebaseService.ts file.

```
  register(username:string, email:string, password:string)
  {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then( (userData) => {resolve(userData), 
      err => reject(err) 
        return userData}) //make sure to return the parameters you want to use in the next .then call.
      .then( (userData) => {
        console.log("The userData is +: " + userData.uid)
      });

    });
```